# Monitoring and restarting docker containers

Tags: docker, nginx, containers, monitoring

I moved my nginx instance to a docker container, I want to monitor that container (or service within it) and be able to launch a new container in case the server restarts or any other issue.

So far what I did to monitor the nginx service in the container, was to add in my consul monitoring a health check, and it is fine (I read a bit about service discovery with consul, no sure if that is the way) but if the container stops I want something to help me to launch a new container.

I have no docker-swarm, kubernetes or other similar orchestrator solution, but I was thinking on some script to use the command `docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 1090:1090 -v /etc/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d nginx`.

Any ideas and advices are welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Use `--restart always` option in `docker run`

Check [this](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/) for more info.

You can also define a custom `healthcheck` on your container.

Check [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#healthcheck) out.